# Django-Filter - Removing filter options that will return empty

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-filter, django-filters

I feel as if I am missing something pretty obvious here. I'm using Django-Filter to filter a ListView and it's working perfectly apart from the fact the options you get in the dropdown menus also include options that will return an empty search query.

I've pre-populated my database with a bunch of data I'm going to need down the line yet isn't currently in use, the "Nations" and "Region" model's specifically.

**Models.py:**

```
class Nation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=False)

class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    nation = models.ForeignKey(Nation, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nation = models.ManyToManyField(Nation, blank=True,)
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region, blank=True,)
```

**Filters.py:**

```
from business.models import Business, BusinessCategory
from locations.models import Nation, Region
import django_filters


class BusinessFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    nation = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        field_name='nation', lookup_expr='isnull',
        queryset=Nation.objects.all().order_by('name')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['business_category', 'nation', 'region']
```

**View.Py:**

```
class BusinessIndexView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 6
    template_name = "business/index.html"
    context_object_name = 'all_business'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter']= BusinessFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Business.objects.filter(live=True).order_by('-id')
```

**Filter.html:**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="mb-2">
<form method="get">
{{filter.form|crispy}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
<a class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0" href="{% url 'business:index' %}">Reset</a>

</form>

</div>
```

Filters.py is where I know it is breaking down.Any help would be much appreciated. I have read through and tried to implement the relative part of the documentation ("[Filtering the related queryset for ModelChoiceFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-related-queryset-for-modelchoicefilter)") but to no avail.

Edit:
The desired functionality is a simple dropdown filter so users can search for a business via the country that the business is associated with.

Example: BBC, UK - Telegraph, UK - CNN, USA- XYZ, USA - etc.

Currently I have a lot of nations added to the database that are not associated with a business yet but will be in the future. I would like to remove "empty" nations from the dropdown list until they have something associated with them.

Using the above example, I have the UK, USA and Canada listed in my filter but only the UK and US should appear as nothing is associated with Canada.

Comment: never worked with this lib but might it be possible that you try to filter by `nation` which isn't a valid field in Nation model? So it returns all objects in the queryset for the dropdown?

Comment: That's exactly what I think is happening. I think it should say something like "queryset=Business.objects.filter(nation=is_valid_nation).order_by('name')" but I'm not totally sure how to validate "is_valid_nation" in that case

Comment: Could you please again describe the desired outcome more specifically, I didn't get it totally yet. Maybe add it to the post. Thanks

Comment: I updated it with a better description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

In you model:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nation = models.ManyToManyField(Nation, blank=True,related_name='businesses')
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region, blank=True,)
```

Filter.py

```
class BusinessFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    nation = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        field_name='nation', lookup_expr='isnull',
        queryset=Nation.objects.exclude(businesses__isnull=True).order_by('name')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['business_category', 'nation', 'region']
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I can't believe it was that simple haha